# Getting remote instance of ThreadMXBean

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I want to call APIs on ThreadMXBean from remote JVM.

example api:

```
    ThreadMXBean.getAllThreadIds()
    ThreadMXBean.getAllThreadCpuTime()
```

I'm looking for actual code snippet instead of general advice.

Essentially, it'd be a call on MBeanServerConnection. I'm able to get attributes, but not able to call operations.

Comment: [this may help you](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ThisFullThreadDumpclassdemonstratesthecapabilitytogetafullthreaddumpandalsodetectdeadlockremotely.htm)

Comment: @BhargavModi I'm looking for how to call MBeanServerConnection.invoke() to call some operations (which accepts parameters) on remote ThreadMXBean.